# Changing T-SQL variable in union statement

Tags: sql, variables, select, union

I want to change a variable value from one part of a union statement to another:

e.g.

```
USE db1
DECLARE @x int;
set @x = 5;
SELECT * FROM  [db1].[Schema1].[table1]
where intCol1 <= @x
UNION
--set @x = 10;  -- doesn't allow me to change variable here
SELECT * FROM  [db1].[Schema1].[table1]
where intCol1 <= @x

-- in this case a work-around would be to use where intCol1 <= (2 * @x) in the last line.
```

But what is the point of variables if you cannot change them?

Is there a away to change the variable to have different values in different parts of the select statement, or is that intrinsically impossible?

Since all numbers < 5 are also < 10, I realize the answer is the same if you just do a single SELECT with where intCol1 <= ( 2* @x)
however, this is a simplified version of a much bigger query scheme ...

Thanks in advance for your attention

Comment: make 2 variables, one for first part of union, one for second.

Comment: that works, but why can't one variable be changed?  That's the whole point of variables, isn't it?

Comment: because its treated as one statement and it is trying to prevent recursion

Comment: Perhaps if you could give us an insight into the actual problem to be solved, we could help. At the moment, all we can see is your "solution" to some unknown problem, and because it's "simplified" we can't see what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually if you change the second line to where intCol1 >= ( 2* @x) it becomes a meaningful problem.

Comment: It would be nice if you could change the variable value in between the parts of the union statement, but I guess that may not be intrinsically possible.  As Kevin C said, one could declare two variables (seems wasteful to me, but I come from a C background not a SQL background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change a variable inside of a SELECT in this way because the computations that happen as part of that statement have no order. SQL Server could execute the second branch first. It would be a highly confusing programming model to allow such things.

A `SELECT` is a specification for the data you want. It is *not* a specification for *how* to retrieve that data, in what order using what access methods.

A `SELECT` is a functional program. You cannot modify state as part of a select. This is a very good thing.

Use two variables.

Answer (score 3):

If you were running multiple steps, you could change the variable between them, but a `UNION` statement is not executed in a stepped fashion.

Comment: @usr Regarding your edit, is it not fair to say that inside of a recursive cte that the anchor executes first and then the recursive portion?

Comment: SQL does not specify an execution model for SELECT. Who knows what transforms the optimizer applies. Certainly, the result order is not guaranteed. Example: If the recursive portion is a constant (`WHERE 0=1`) it is "executed" as part of plan compilation (by deleting it).